# How To use a stored procedure in a crystal reports 8.5?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have to make a new report using crystal report8.5 .
I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005. The stored procedure has one input parameter.

Now I wanna to know that how I can add that stored procedure and show its result in my report
while designing that report?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to File > Options > Database (going from memory) and make sure the checkbox for Stored Procedures is ticked. Then, when you setup your connection to SQL Server, as well as a Tables section you'll see a Stored Procedures one beneath it. Find your stored procedure in the list, add it as the data source for your report, and you'll be able to use it as a normal source.

Comment: Thank you , Excellent, but still there is another problem: 
when I make a new connection using "OLEDB", I can see tables and stored procedures but can not add it to the report, I mean, Add button is disabled....what's wrong with it?