# pass parameters to stored procedure from crystal reports designer

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

how to pass parameters to stored procedure from crystal reports designer
and in code also ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To use a stored procedure in a crystal reports 8.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736894/how-to-use-a-stored-procedure-in-a-crystal-reports-8-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use required stored procedure as source for report, while building report itself, you can pass stored procedure parameters from code as the following;

```
ReportDocument rptDocument = new ReportDocument();

// Load report.
rptDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("rptFileNameOrPath"));

ParameterFields parameterFields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterField parameterField = null;
ParameterDiscreteValue parameterValue = null;

parameterField = new ParameterField();
parameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
parameterField.Name = "@ContactId";
parameterValue.Value = "1";
parameterField.CurrentValues.Add(parameterValue);
parameterFields.Add(parameterField);
this.rptDocument.SetParameterValue("@ContactId", parameterValue);
```

`@ContactId:` is a parameter for required stored procedure.

Finally, you can either export report or print it based on your requirements.

```
// 0, 0: to print all the pages.
this.rptDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Regarding Crystal Report Designer, you just use *View Report* option, you will be asked to enter values for all report parameters, just enter required values.